# Web scrabbing google search results without getting detected

Tags: python, selenium, web, search, automation

I have about 100000 links to copy from a google search result. I wrote a python code using selenium to make my life easier but as soon as i arrive to around 150 results the google search result page changes, as i think that google is detecting my scrabber. Here is a sample of my code:

```
links = []

# Extracting the 10 links in the google page
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
sleep(randTime(0,1))
search = soup.find_all('div', class_="yuRUbf")
for h in search:
    links.append(h.a.get('href'))
sleep(randTime(0,1))

#Clicking the next button
next_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='pnnext']") 
sleep(randTime(0,5))
next_button.click()
sleep(randTime(2,10))
```

I would really appreciate any help from you, I'm using random sleeps during my code execution put they are not working. Do you suggest anything to help?

This is the error I am getting:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@id='pnnext']"}
(Session info: headless chrome=90.0.4430.93)
```

Comment: What makes you think you are being detected exactly? and um... I can't say with certainty but I believe something circumventing anti-automation security is against the stackoverflow TOS.

Comment: I get element not found exception for the next button

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I don't know if or how they are detecting that you are using automation. But there's one trick I know of that you can try... I can't give any guarantee that it will work for google. This sounds hacky and it is. If you do this make sure to make a copy of your chromedriver first:

In the chromedriver binary itself, if you try with some searching tool, you will find, if I remember correctly, quite a lot of strings containing `cdc_`. These strings will look like `$cdc_hqpiuakajldvcZf`, or whatever gibberish. What you want to do is **replace** all of the characters in those strings, BUT retain both the number of characters and the positioning of the underscore, and the $. So for example I might change the above string to `$fws_nfkdishwlkdbcof`. If you don't have the right number of characters chromedriver will crash and burn.

The reason this can work is that some detection software clues in on variables with the `cdc` in them, to know that you are using a browser driver. Let me know if you try this and how it goes.

Comment: Is cdc_ an attribute in the driver that i need to reset in each loop?

Comment: No -- it is part of the chromedriver binary file itself. You don't need to write any code to do this, a text editor is fine. I'm not sure if you know where your `chromedriver.exe` file is but you can google the standard location for your operating system and track it down.

Comment: I'm using google colab which is a cloud service for running your code. So i don't know how  will i access the driver file, any clues?

Comment: I don't know. If it turns out you don't have access to it, you can always download and use your own `chromium-chromedriver`

Comment: Yes of course i downloaded it but its on cloud, as everything is.

Comment: I mean, you could do so as part of your python script, with `!pip install selenium
!apt-get update 
!apt install chromium-chromedriver` or whatever

Comment: Yes i did, but how would i change the cdc_ values?

Comment: Shoot, good point. I'm not even sure it's worth putting in tons of effort to try this, unless it's very important for you to solve your issue.